# Zxing lib. does not work above Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, zxing

I have successfully integrated **zxing** `core.jar` library below android **Marshmallow**, but while integrating this into above Marshmallow, it gives me following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: NO activity found to handle
intent{act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check and post the merged manifest from your project? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087870/manifest-merger-it-is-possible-to-see-the-resulting-mixed-manifest

Comment: yes. but when i register CaptureActivity from core.jar library it gives me error. activity not found.

Comment: We can't help you without more code like your manifest :)

Answer (score 0):

@ Kevin Robatel 
my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and following code executes onClick of button

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        //intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, BARCODE_CAPTURE_ACTIVITY);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Scanner Not Found "+anfe.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in runtime permission of Camera. Try to give an access it to your app in code or manually

Answer (score 0):

You should edit code at Manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And don't forget add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```