# How to find where install_referrer intent broadcast is used?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

We received a notice from Google today stating that one of our apps uses the install_referrer intent broadcast mechanism that will be disabled soon.  I am unable to figure out where it is used.  As far as I know, the app does not use it.

Could anyone offer a tip on how to find out where it is used?

Comment: Probably your app has one of the 3rd party libs such as `AppsFlyer` which uses this. The broadcast receiver must be registered in `AndroidManifest`. If you open your app's manifest in Android Studio and select `merged` view, you can see the merged manifest. Maybe that will help you identify it.

Comment: @Froyo Great idea.  I did not know this tool.  I looked at Merged Manifest, but could not find any relevant entries, unfortunately. I even opened every source manifest listed on the right panel, and searched "install", but could not find any. I opened AndroidManifest.xml in the app's apk, but it seems to be encoded.

Comment: @Froyo I used Build > Analyze APK.. > Open app-official-debug.apk > open AndroidManifest.xml, but still could not find any relevant entries.

Comment: How to show merged AndroidManifest.xml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55122593/5146268