# Android Deep link opens with "Launch URL" but not with typing exact url

Tags: android, android-intent, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

I've been using Android's implicit deep links and I've defined my deep link directly inside my navigation graph.

The problem is when I use "Launch Options" in configurations like below my deep link will open the fragment just fine, but when I type the exact URL it won't work (btw I tried typing with http, https, without it, in a note app and in the browser directly).

[image]

Any guesses why this happens?

Some parts of my code related:
navigation_graph :

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/usedPriceFragment"
        android:name="UsedPriceFragment"
        android:label="UsedPriceFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="clearCache"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            app:argType="boolean"
            app:nullable="false" />
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:action="ACTION_VIEW"
            app:mimeType="type/subtype"
            app:uri="example.com/example/prices/used" />
    </fragment>
```

manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/example/prices" />
            </intent-filter>
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/navigation_graph_main" />
```

**Edit**:
Detailed version: The system asks me if I want to open the URL with my app. I click yes and then the home page starts up instead of the fragment I wanted to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when opening an activity in `singleTask` mode you need to handle the received intent manually. So adding this line of code fixed the problem.

```
if (mainActivity.tabManager.findActiveNavController()?.handleDeepLink(intent) == true) {
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing deep links by typing them in the browser isn't generally a good idea. The browser will often try to handle the URL itself, and won't pass it to the OS.

You should instead send the intent via ADB itself, like so:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "http://domain.name:optional_port"
```

Further information is available [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#testing) for app links.

As a side note, I'm assuming `example.com` in your code is placeholder text. If not, when you use `autoVerify="true"` it must be to a domain you control, and have [set up verification for](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations).

Comment: Thank you for putting the time to write an answer. Yes, the `example.com` is just a placeholder; but even with the command you wrote, my fragment is not being opened and there is not log inside LogCat. I typed `https://example.com/example/prices/used` exactly but still no luck.

Comment: Actually, the system asks me if I want to open the url with my app. I click yes and then the home page starts up instead of the fragment I wanted to open.

Comment: That's much more promising, at least it's in your app! Not sure I can help more, sorry, perhaps the `mimeType` needs checking?

Comment: I tried removing it and that didn't work too.

Comment: What if you remove the `intent-filter` you've added, and rely on the autogenerated one?

Comment: I just tried that too, still no luck :(
It will open up the app home page though still. Is there anyway to check the generated files for a deep link?

Comment: Out of ideas, sorry! Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087870/manifest-merger-it-is-possible-to-see-the-resulting-mixed-manifest

Comment: Thank you for putting out you time :)

Comment: I just found the problem, I posted the answer below :)