# Play console does not consider uses-feature -> required="false" in manifest for android app bundle

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-console, telephonymanager, uses-feature

I am trying to publish app bundle on play store. It shows wifi only tablet not supported because of android.hardware.telephony feature. I set this feature's required flag to false. But still play console shows the same error in device catalogue. Any idea why it is showing an error as not supported device samsung galaxy A7 lite (wifi only)?

I am checking this problem in a following way: I upload app bundle then I save it. Before publishing I go to device catalogue to check the supported devices for the same app bundle. And there I see an error.

**My AndroidManifest permissions and features:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        
        <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                android:required="false"
                tools:node="replace"/>
        
            <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
                android:required="false"
                tools:node="replace"/>
        
            <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
                android:required="false"
                tools:node="replace"/>
```

**Merged manifest:**

[image: Merged Manifest file]

**Play console error:**

> Doesn't support required feature: android.hardware.telephony

Comment: Can you share your [merged manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55122593/608312) (not your app's `AndroidManifest.xml`) please? If it includes anything to do with calls / SMS, telephony may be being added automatically. I can't see anything obviously wrong from what you've shared though, your `uses-feature` should solve it regardless.

Comment: @JakeLee I have added merged manifest also. Please check and let me know if you find any problem. Also I have added the steps I do to check the device support.

Comment: Hmm, nothing jumps out at me, sorry. Hope you find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved. For others I am putting an answer here. It's funny that I just ignored that device catalogue for the saved release and rolled it out directly. That manifest changes started working for the release and play console started showing **supported** for the device which was unsupported previously. :)

For those who are not clear, it's simple. Just check your merged manifest file properly -> update your manifest file (feature flags etc.) as per your requirements (remove unwanted permissions, features. make them non mandatory if possible) -> go ahead and publish your build -> after publishing device catalogue shows newly supported devices and removes earlier errors. Don't check device catalogue before publishing.

Comment: can you tell clearly how did you solve this

Comment: I agree, this was nt clear. Can you please make it a tiny bit clearer, I am encountering this same issue now too.