# google play console rejects my application for QUERY_ALL_PACKAGE

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I hope you have a good day, Google says that I should use a lower visibility, but the truth is that I do not have such a package in my androidmanifest.

In the middle of my investigation I found that some of my dependencies may be using this permission, but I don't know which ones they may be. In my application policies declare the file picker and url_launcher dependencies and that the policies say "Allowed uses include the following: device search, antivirus applications, file managers and browsers."
But my application keeps getting rejected, what should I do

[pubspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar55K.png)

androidManifest in android studio:
[image]

Mi androidmanifest

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="">
 <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
      calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
      In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
      additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
      FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
   
 <application
 android:allowBackup="false"
     android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
     android:label=""
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

   
<!-- <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
   android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" /> -->
<!-- <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/incon" /> -->
<!-- <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
   android:resource="@color/launch_background" /> -->
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
<!-- <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
           android:resource="@color/colorAccent" /> -->

   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTop"
       android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
       android:showWhenLocked="true"
       android:turnScreenOn="true"
       android:exported="true">


     <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
          the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
          while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
          to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
     <meta-data
         android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
         android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
         />
         <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
 android:value="high_importance_channel" />
 
     <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
          Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
          screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
          gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
          Flutter's first frame. -->
     <meta-data
         android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
         android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
         />
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
        This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
   <meta-data
       android:name="flutterEmbedding"
       android:value="2" />
   <service
       android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ForegroundService"
       
       android:stopWithTask="false"/>
       <service
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>

       
 </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

 <!-- <queries>
   
   <intent>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <data android:scheme="https" />
   </intent>
 </queries> -->
</manifest> ```
````

Comment: Check your merged manifest. You probably have some third-party library that is requesting this permission.

Comment: how to see merged manifest?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, if you open your manifest file, you will see a "Merged Manifest" sub-tab.

Comment: According to this answer I don't have a "merged manifest" https://stackoverflow.com/a/55122593/17290091, I'll attach an image in my question