# Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher required explicit value `android:exported` when coresponding component has intent filter

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-12

**Here is my app manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="XYZ">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ReadMCQActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ReadActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LeaderBoardMCQ"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.VerifyFP"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ForgotPassword"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.PrivacyActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ContactActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LegalityActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.TermsActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.TopWinners"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SelectBank"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.BankActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ImagePickerActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.BattleAttribute"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LivePlay"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LiveAttribute"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.TournamentPlay"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.BattlePlay"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.TournamentAttribute"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Congarts"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Prizepool"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LeaderBoard"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ReadMore"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Account"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Wallet"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Home"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.VerifyNumberOTP"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Signup"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Boarding"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Splash"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.razorpay.ApiKey"
            android:value="XYZ" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Here is my build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    namespace 'XYZ'
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XYZ"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.realpacific:click-shrink-effect:2.0'
    implementation 'io.github.shashank02051997:FancyToast:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
    //dexter permissions
    implementation "com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0"
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.github.basusingh:BeautifulProgressDialog:1.001'
    implementation 'com.github.OzcanAlasalvar:DatePicker:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.aabhasr1:OtpView:v1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mejdi14:Flat-Dialog-Android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.dimorinny:floating-text-button:0.0.4'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.12'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
}
```

I tried to put android:exported:true or false according rules but still getting the error while running code.
It was working untill the version 30 but after upgrading to latest 33 according to google play store its showing error.
Please help me out if anyone have solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There may be some component coming from a library . Inspect  [Merge manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087870/manifest-merger-it-is-possible-to-see-the-resulting-mixed-manifest) for such component .. if u find any then u might have upgrade that library to latest version .

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade All dependencies when upgrading to SDKVersion '33'**

SDK '33' not support those projects or libraries that are not targeting SDKVersion '33'